# React using ref to disable button while adding a message isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to disable the button after one finishes clicking on the `Add` button in the Price Popup window. I found an article that talks about using callback refs to disable a button (https://www.johnnolan.dev/ideas/2019/01/13/react-callbacks-refs.html).

I believe that my code was successful when I use the advice to disable the button on click. However, when I tried to add the code for making a message appear when the button is disabled, I noticed that if I click on the `X` button to delete a price in the price list, the message also appears. How do I edit the code to make the message only appear if the `Add` button was clicked?

Here's a part of my code in the React app:

```
<button
     type="button"
     onClick={this.addPricePopup}
     className="btn add-button"
     ref={btnReview  => {this.btnReview = btnReview;}}
     >Add +
</button>
  {this.state.addPricePopup && (
      <AddPriceForm
         addPrice={this.addPrice}
          cancelPopup={this.addPricePopup}
       />
   )}
   {this.btnReview ? "testing" : ""}
```

and here's the function that was called in this same component in my React app:

```
addPricePopup = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      addPricePopup: !prevState.addPricePopup
    }));
    this.btnReview.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  };
```

You can check the problem out in my demo at CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kikidesignnet/caissa. You can see that the message will appear if you click on the `Price` button, and then click on the `Add` button in the Price Popup window. You can also notice that after you close and then reopen the Price Popup window, but instead, click on the `X` button to delete a price from the price list, that the message will also appear.

Comment: There may be simpler, more "react-y" ways to accomplish disabling a button. Typically direct DOM manipulations are seen as an anti-pattern in React. React provides all the tooling and mechanisms necessary to set a `disabled` prop/attribute on an element.

Comment: oh... Okay, then I'll look in other React solutions to set a `disabled` attribute on `Add` button

Comment: Super simple - `<button disabled={/* some state, prop, or computed truthy/falsey value */} ...>`